# How Find Date Time And year From Given Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Find Date Time And Years From Given Integer.

Explain: I have a fild Which Is Membership Period (Int) i Want To Find Out Date FromDate and UpToDate From Given Integer.

if Membership Period is = 65 Than I want FromDate= 29-01-2017 (current date) and UpToDate=04-03-2017 i want as like this. how to do that..please advice...thanks..

Comment: Are you looking for the `.AddDays()` method of `DateTime`?

Comment: Can you explain the logic?

Comment: yes i Want .AddDays() method .if i take a integer value like 10 .i want to convert this integer date time format. means if today date is 29-01-2017 then i want this integer 10 add in to today date and giving me result as 08-02-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it

```
DateTime currentdate= DateTime.Now; //return the current date
DateTime UpToDate = now.AddDays(65);
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the DateTime subtracted the number of days(int) you input.

```
private static DateTime Subtract(int input)
    {
        return DateTime.Today.AddDays(-input);
    }
```